# Compare rows each other of a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a dataframe (csv file) which looks like that :

```
   proteins    query    E-value   from   to 
0   prot_1       PP2     4e-09     195   221 
1   prot_6       PP2     3e-05     437   460 
2   prot_5       PP2     4.7e-09   203   271 
3   prot_2       PP2     1.2e-03   322   375 
4   prot_2       PP2     2.6e-05   376   413 
5   prot_2       PP2     0.3e-09   455   506 
6   prot_3       PPR     0.13      109   160 
7   prot_3       RPD     0.47      227   278 
8   prot_6       PTT     0.6e-08   455   558 
9   prot_2       DYW     1.6e-09   509   702 
10  prot_4       DYW     8.8e-09   444   640 
11  prot_1       PEQ     10e-09    183   212 
12  prot_1       QTQ     0.13      147   179 
13  prot_3       QTQ     2e-19     316   337
```

Each row shows the probability (E-value column) of presence of a certain query in the protein sequence.
So i want to iterate over all rows in order to find if some queries overlap same protein and chose the one with best E-value (query with smallest E-value)
For i.e. prot_1, queries PP2 (204 to 221) and PEQ (183 to 212) overlap in their interval so the one i have to keep is P2.

I know it's not the efficient way, iterate over dataframe rows, but i've tried it and...i don't get what i want:

```
data = pandas.read_csv("filename.csv")
df = pandas.DataFrame(data)

for row1 in df['proteins']:
    for row2 in df['proteins'] :
            # Coordinates
            row1_Coord = [df.loc[df['proteins']==row1,'from'].values[0],df.loc[df['proteins']==row1,'to'].values[0]]
            row2_Coord = [df.loc[df['proteins']==row2,'from'].values[0], df.loc[df['proteins']==row2,'to'].values[0]]
            # Query names
            row1_Query = df.loc[df['proteins']==row1,'query'].values[0]
            row2_Query = df.loc[df['proteins']==row2,'query'].values[0]
            # Proteines names
            row1_Prot = df.loc[df['proteins']==row1,'proteins'].values[0]
            row2_Prot = df.loc[df['proteins']==row2,'proteins'].values[0]

            '''Criterion to find overlapping:
                i.e. 2 sequences A(a0,a1) and B(b0,b1) with their coordinates:
                There is an overlapping if among both :
                (min(a[1], b[1]) - max(a[0], b[0]) > 0       
            '''
            if((row1_Prot == row2_Prot) and (row1_Query != row2_Query) and (min(row1_Coord[1],row2_Coord[1]) - max(row1_Coord[0],row2_Coord[0])) > 0) :
               # do something...
```

I realize that there is no output with the 3 conditions in the if state.
Do you have some tricks, some advices in order to solve this problem, something like not to iterate over all rows of a huge file, just compare rows with same protein name and find overlapping.
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Nice question! Getting rid of the for loops is almost impossible in this case, but using `groupby` helps a lot. Give this a try:

```py
import pandas

# Sample dataset
df = pandas.DataFrame([
    {"proteins": "prot_1", "query": "PP2", "E-value": 4e-09, "from": 195, "to": 221},
    {"proteins": "prot_6", "query": "PP2", "E-value": 3e-05, "from": 437, "to": 460},
    {"proteins": "prot_5", "query": "PP2", "E-value": 4.7e-09, "from": 203, "to": 271},
    {"proteins": "prot_2", "query": "PP2", "E-value": 1.2e-03, "from": 322, "to": 375},
    {"proteins": "prot_2", "query": "PP2", "E-value": 2.6e-05, "from": 376, "to": 413},
    {"proteins": "prot_2", "query": "PP2", "E-value": 0.3e-09, "from": 455, "to": 506},
    {"proteins": "prot_3", "query": "PPR", "E-value": 0.13, "from": 109, "to": 160},
    {"proteins": "prot_3", "query": "RPD", "E-value": 0.47, "from": 227, "to": 278},
    {"proteins": "prot_6", "query": "PTT", "E-value": 0.6e-08, "from": 455, "to": 558},
    {"proteins": "prot_2", "query": "DYW", "E-value": 1.6e-09, "from": 509, "to": 702},
    {"proteins": "prot_4", "query": "DYW", "E-value": 8.8e-09, "from": 444, "to": 640},
    {"proteins": "prot_1", "query": "PEQ", "E-value": 10e-09, "from": 183, "to": 212},
    {"proteins": "prot_1", "query": "QTQ", "E-value": 0.13, "from": 147, "to": 179},
    {"proteins": "prot_3", "query": "QTQ", "E-value": 2e-19, "from": 316, "to": 337},
])


def find_overlaps(group: pandas.DataFrame) -> pandas.DataFrame:
    """ Method to filter overlapping queries per protein.

    Args:
        group (pandas.DataFrame): A dataframe containing only a single protein (e.g. from a groupby)

    Returns:
        pandas.DataFrame: Filtered dataframe, removed overlap based on probability
    """

    # Skip groups with only a single row (overlap is impossible)
    if group.shape[0] <= 1:
        return group

    # Keep a list of indices that should be dropped
    to_drop = []

    # Loop over the rows (not ideal, but there's not really a different way in this case)
    for index, row in group.iterrows():

        # Turn the ranges for this protein into an interval array (without the current row)
        intervals_array = pandas.arrays.IntervalArray(group.drop(index)["range"])

        # Check which rows overlap with this row
        overlapping_rows = intervals_array.overlaps(row["range"])

        # If no rows overlap, skip to the next row
        if not any(overlapping_rows):
            continue

        # Select the rows that overlap each other
        overlap_selection = group.drop(index).loc[overlapping_rows].append(group.loc[index])

        # Get the index of the row with the highest probability (lowest E-value)
        highest_probability_index = overlap_selection["E-value"].idxmin()

        # Add all other rows that overlap but don't have the highest probability, to the list to drop
        to_drop += overlap_selection.drop(highest_probability_index).index.tolist()

    # Return the original group, without the rows that should be dropped
    return group.drop(to_drop)


# Convert the ranges to Pandas ranges
df["range"] = df.apply(lambda row: pandas.Interval(row["from"], row["to"], closed='neither'), axis=1)

# Filter the overlaps, keep from overlapping queries, the highest probability
df = df.groupby(["proteins"]).apply(find_overlaps).droplevel(0).sort_index().drop(columns=["range"])
print(df)
```